# converting char * into vector C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a memory which I use `char * p` to access it.

I want a reference to it. How do I make it?

```
vector<char>& v = p
```

What do I need to do instead of p to convert it to vector, I need also to tell it the size of the char * that I use in the memory.

Comment: It is not possible for a `std::vector` to use a reference to existing memory.  You can reference the memory after the `std::vector` is created or you can initialize the `std::vector` with the contents of data in memory.

Comment: What kind of vector do you want? What kind of data is at the pointed to location? It's hard to answer this question without more information but the most straight forward solution is probably to cast p to the correct type of pointer, and then construct a new vector using something like std::vector<char> wewvec(p,p+20) that is, if the data is really char.

Comment: What are you going to do with the reference? Why can't you just use p? Such as: p[3], ?

Comment: If a refernce to char *p is needed, you can make a reference to pointer like that: char *&ref = p; I suppose that there is a function that takes a reference to pointer just as in void function_a(int *& a)

Comment: Is there a function that expects a reference? If a reference to char *p is needed, you can make a reference to pointer like that: char *&ref = p; I suppose that there is a function that takes a reference to pointer just as in void fun(char *& a). By this way if you call fun(p) your pointer will be passed by reference. If the function was something like void fun(char &a) you would call it as fun((*p)).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this question without more information but I'll try. The most straight forward solution is probably to cast p to the correct type of pointer, and then construct a new vector. If you want a vector of chars:

```
std::vector<char> wewvec(p,p+20)
```

where 20 is where you'll give the number of element. That is, if the data is really char.

If the data is of some other type, say it contains 20 floats, you could do:

```
const float* pf=reinterpret_cast<const float*>(p);
std::vector<float> wewvec(pf,pf+20)
```

As Dietrich writes, this will *copy* the data into the new vector.

Comment: [`error: invalid static_cast from type ‘const char*’ to type ‘const float*’`](https://ideone.com/EnAOIu)

Comment: Thank you, that's embarrassing. should be reinterpret_cast. https://ideone.com/ox5Uxz

Answer (score 1):

Essentially:

- A vector owns its memory, it doesn't just reference it. So you can create a new vector which copies your data, but you cannot get the vector to "acquire" your pointer and use that.
- If you have to have a vector to pass into a 3rd party API and you have a pointer, you will have to make a copy
- If you are in control of the API, you could change it to take a range of pointers (begin / end) or a pointer and a size. This way, if you have a vector already you can still access these functions (albeit you cannot expect `begin()` and `end()` to give you pointers. But there are ways to get these as pointers using `&v[0]` and then adding the size to that pointer).
- If you just need to put the data into standard algorithms, you can already do that with a pointer.

Obviously you cannot perform vector operations that modify the data size e.g. push_back if you have a pointer. But as you have a `char*` not a `const char*`, you can modify the members.

Comment: "But you cannot get the vector to acquire your pointer" that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pointer p that points to a memory block

```
char* p = new char[100];
```

you can create a reference to it by writing

```
char& q = *p;
```

if you use the container `vector` you will need to copy the contents to the vector as Johan says

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find a way without copying it

Comment: @Boris: That's a non-starter.